# KMS Key Exposure

Tags: key-management, aws

I've found some KMS key exposed in some code and am wondering what exactly the severity would be.

What could an attacker achieve by having this key?

Comment: What is the key *to*?

Comment: Do you mean the actual key material? Or just the ARN of the KMS key?

Comment: @keithRozario the ARN